# ACF: Is there a limit on the amount of text in a field?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

The child field in it is a text field with visual editing:

[image: Screenshot of ACF fields]

And for some reason when I enter a lot of text the page simply does not load a white screen without errors.

[image: Screenshot of WYSIWYG field filled with text]

Here is the output of the field in the code:

[image: Screenshot of PHP template file using these ACF fields]

Does ACF has text length restrictions? The documentation doesn't say anything about this.

After I deleted two paragraphs from the text field, the page loaded.

Comment: Have you checked the [debug log](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#wp_debug_log) yet? If so, does it contain any error messages?

Comment: no, it is empty, for the test I replaced h2 with h3. And it has earned such an opinion that it has a limit on the number of tags in the editor, which is also strange. And why didn't it give any error.